# Amazon Kinesis Firehose - How to pause a stream?

Tags: amazon-kinesis-firehose

I need the ability to pause a stream in AWS Kinesis Firehose.

I need it when I need to perform a schema change that requires re-creation of the table (just for example, change in sortkey).

Those changes usually require creating a new table inserting the rows to the new table, the dropping the original table and renaming the new table to the original name. Doing this will result in loss of rows that were streamed during this process.

I can think on two workarounds:

1. **Renaming the original table at the begging of process**, then force firehose to fail, and retry until you make the change and rename it back. I am not sue if the retry mechanism is bullet proof enough for this.
2. **Defining a time interval of few hours** (as needed) in between the loads, then watching the "COPY" queries, and doing the same as #1 just after the COPY. Thisi s jsut a bi more safe than #1.

Both workarounds doesn't feels lek a best practice, under statement.

Is there a better solution?
How bullet prof my solutions are?

Comment: Looking for the path of least resistance, or perhaps better phrased as "whats the minimum amount of work I can do". I think workaround 1 sounds good, at least for your example where the schemas not going to change in any way that needs the incoming records to change.

We're planning on a cluster resize which inevitably will involve some downtime. I think its worth noting that if firehose keeps failing past its retry limit, you get a manifest file written to S3 detailing the data it couldnt load, so once the downtime is over, running an adhoc copy using those manifests should be easy

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue and did the following. Note: for this method to work, you must have timestamps (`created_at` in the answer below) on the events you are ingesting into Redshift from Kinesis.

1. Assume `table1` is the table you already have, and Kinesis is dumping events into it from `firehose1`.
2. Create a new firehose, `firehose2`, that dumps events to a new table, `table2`, which has the same schema as `table1`.
3. Once you can confirm that events are landing in `table2`, and `max(created_at)` in `table1` is less than `min(created_at)` in `table2`, delete `firehose1`. We can now be sure we will not lose any data because there is already an overlap between `table1` and `table2`.
4. Create a table `table3` that has the same schema as `table1`. Copy all events from `table1` into `table3`.
5. Drop `table1` and recreate it, this time with the sort key.
6. Recreate `firehose1` to continue dumping events into `table1`.
7. Once events start landing in `table1` again, confirm that `min(created_at)` in `table1` is less than `max(created_at)` in `table2`. When this is true, delete `firehose2`.
8. Copy all events from `table2` with `created_at` strictly greater than `max(created_at)` in `table3` and strictly less than `min(created_at)` in `table1` into `table1`. If your system allows events with the same timestamp, there may be duplicates introduced in this step.
9. Copy all events from `table3` back into the new `table1`.

EDIT: You can avoid using `table3` if you use `alter table` to rename `table1` to `table1_old` and then make `table2` above the new `table1`.

Comment: This method could also be tweaked to handle the case where there are more significant schema changes, perhaps where the incoming data has changes too

Answer (score 0):

Since AWS Kinesis Stream can store data (by default 1 day and up to a year [but more than 24 hours additional charges will be applied](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-extended-retention.html)), I recommend to delete the Delivery Stream (Kinesis Firehose) and once you are done with upgrade/maintenance work you easily can re-configure a new delivery stream.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).